# New variable with #define

Tags: c++, variables, c-preprocessor

I'd like to create variables "automatically" with #declare. So, I don't want to type to new variable's class definition many times (actually I'm declaring multidimensional vectors, not simple integers...)

I have this code:

```
#define inti(aa)(int (aa)=3)

...

inti(a);
```

But the compiler says:

> "error: 'a' was not declared in this scope"

Is it possible to solve this problem in C++? Please help!

Comment: Are you really going to declare **so many** int variables that will be initialized to 3 that you require this macro? You should try to avoid macros. More than anything if you are using them for such a trivial task.

Comment: It's going to take a lot of effort to be that lazy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<del>Use:</del>

```
 #define inti(aa) int aa=3
```

That's because

```
(int aa=3);
```

is illegal, even more what you have there.

Actually, scratch that. **Don't use a macro**. Just declare your variables the good old-fashioned way.

> actually I'm declaring multidimensional vectors

+1 for the question for stating your **actual** problem. This is what a `typedef` is for.

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<int> > MDVector;
MDVector multiDimensionalVector;
```

Comment: @balping please use a `typedef` instead.

Comment: What are your problems with macros??

Comment: @balping there are tons of answers on stackoverflow regarding macros. I'm sure you can find them.

Comment: @balping, macros ignore scope and give confusing errors if something goes wrong. There's two problems right there. `typedef` does not ignore scope, and gives a structured error.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `typedef` instead of a `#define` like this:

```
typedef complexClassName<PossiblyWithManyTemplateParameters> Name
Name var1;
Name var2;
Name var3;
```

if you don't want to type the long name many times.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore
That's not enough because I declare the size of the vector too:

`#define vecdec(vecvec)vector<vector<vector<bool> > > vecvec(9,vector<vector<bool> >(9,vector <bool>(9,true))) `